# Can't add Constraint

Tags: php, laravel-5

I kept getting this exception:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL  
  : alter table `messages` add constraint messages_from_foreign foreign key (  
  `from`) references `id` (`users`))     

[PDOException]                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Here's my `CreateMessagesTable` class:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('from', false, true);
            ...

            $table->foreign('from')->references('users')->on('id');
        });
    }
```

And here's my `CreateUsersTable` class:

```
public function up()
    {
        // http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->bigInteger('id', true, true);

           ...
        });
    }
```

I tried to double check if I had the same data type for column `id` in `users` and `from` in `messages`, and they were. I wonder what is wrong and why I keep getting constraint error messages.

Comment: Do you have data already in the table that would break the constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$table->foreign('from')->references('users')->on('id');
```

The values should be the other way around - `on` uses the table name and `references` points to the column on that table.

Source: [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#foreign-keys)